# PostgreSQL exception while performing insert

Tags: java, postgresql

I need your help. I want to write from java into ProstgreSQL but the tables are all empty. After checking the logs, I found this:

```
[#|2018-03-29T09:13:52.689+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=151;_ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool1;|javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5240)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5138)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4926)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2047)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EjbAsyncTask.call(EjbAsyncTask.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.4.v20160520-8886999): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO cats (ID, CAT, CAT_C, CAT_E, CAT_CE, CAT_L, CAT_LV, CAT_N, CAT_O, CAT_P, CAT_R, CAT_T) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [12 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.lel.b2v.ddd.model.CategoryDataDb@181bce9c)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:785)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:418)
    at com.lel.b2v.ddd.service.CategoryCacheUpdaterHelper.updateDatabase(CategoryCacheUpdaterHelper.java:174)
    at com.lel.b2v.ddd.service.CategoryCacheUpdaterHelper.addCategoriesForAllLanguagesToDb(CategoryCacheUpdaterHelper.java:117)
    at com.lel.b2v.ddd.service.CategoryCacheUpdaterHelper.updateCache(CategoryCacheUpdaterHelper.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5413)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5385)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5373)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EjbAsyncTask.call(EjbAsyncTask.java:101)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.4.v20160520-8886999): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

I'm searching for about 2 days to find the problem, but I can't find it.

This is the code performing the update:

```js
private void updateDb(final List<CategoryDataDb> mappedCategories) {
        if (!mappedCategories.isEmpty()) {
            // Remove all entries when we know the result
            this.em.createQuery("DELETE FROM CatDb r", CategoryDataDb.class).executeUpdate();
            for (final CategoryDataDb newDbCategory : mappedCategories) {
                this.em.merge(newDbCategory);

            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn(
                    "Error.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some actual code please?

Comment: It may helps: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/001701c53a90$cf879cc0$6600a8c0@kermit

Comment: @A.Bandtock updated question. Inserted code.

Comment: Well, it's an IO error, so the code doesn't matter much. It's about network settings and such.

Comment: Looks like a connection timeout, ensure the db connection is kept alive if you're going to reuse it.

Comment: @A.Bandtock how can I do this in the code?

Comment: Looks like the connection between JDBC driver and PostgreSQL server failed. Look in the PostgreSQL log if the server crashed. If not, check your network setup (firewalls etc.) if it randomly drops innocent TCP connections.